# How to transpose query result?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have simple query like below :

```
SELECT distinct DateTime , Result , count(Result)as total
  FROM [lfplog].[dbo].[d_lfpLog] group by datetime, result order by DateTime, result asc
```

And from that query, the output is like this :
DateTime    Result  total

```
**Date Time   Result      total**
2021-04-01  00000000    20
2021-04-01  00000028    10
2021-04-01  000000FF    9
2021-04-01  000001FF    2
2021-04-01  000004FF    58
2021-04-01  000005FF    4
2021-04-01  000006FF    4
2021-04-01  000007FB    3
2021-04-01  000007FF    467
2021-04-02  000000FF    2
2021-04-02  000004FF    1
2021-04-02  000007FF    13
2021-04-03  00000000    220
2021-04-03  00000028    16
2021-04-03  0000003F    1
2021-04-03  00000040    1
2021-04-03  000000FB    1
2021-04-03  000000FF    24
2021-04-03  00000100    3
2021-04-03  00000102    1
2021-04-03  000001FB    1
2021-04-03  000001FF    4
2021-04-03  000004FB    1
2021-04-03  000004FF    179
2021-04-03  00000500    1
2021-04-03  000005BB    1
2021-04-03  000005FB    2
2021-04-03  000005FF    15
2021-04-03  000006FF    8
2021-04-03  0000073F    50
2021-04-03  000007BA    2
2021-04-03  000007BF    2
2021-04-03  000007FA    1
2021-04-03  000007FB    22
2021-04-03  000007FF    1706
2021-04-04  00000000    2
2021-04-04  00000008    2
2021-04-04  00000010    12
2021-04-04  00000028    24
2021-04-04  0000003A    1
2021-04-04  0000003B    2
2021-04-04  0000003F    1
2021-04-04  00000068    1
2021-04-04  0000007B    1
2021-04-04  0000007F    1
2021-04-04  000000FB    1
2021-04-04  000000FF    26
2021-04-04  0000013F    1
2021-04-04  000001FF    3
2021-04-04  000004FB    1
2021-04-04  000004FF    77
2021-04-04  000005FF    14
2021-04-04  000006FF    4
2021-04-04  000007AB    1
2021-04-04  000007FB    31
2021-04-04  000007FF    1062
```

What i am looking for is, how to transpose those Date Time from row to column ?
My expected result table are like this :

```
             2021-04-01       2021-04-02        2021-04-03
00000000     20               34                35
00000000     10               65                76
00000028     9                7                 98
000000FF     2                8                 87
000001FF     58               9                 34
000004FF     343              23                98
000005FF     34               23                87
000006FF     23               3                 2
```

Is it possible to do it in sql server query or procedure?
Or should I process it in the back code? (I am using c#)
Any help would be appreciate
Thank you

Comment: Are the dates always known to be exactly the three dates you showed above?

Comment: no, the date is daily date, so every day the data inserted automatically to database and I just need to summarize (count) it daily by Result column. Is it possible to do it in sql server query ?

Comment: I am not sure about the answer but [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201320/Dynamic-Pivoting-with-Cubes-and-eventhandlers-in-S) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct is redundant here

You can do it in sql or the front end; sql knows how to do it already whereas the front end will need something coding up to do it or use of a reporting library that knows how to crosstab. Doing it in sqls makes the results slightly harder to work with because the column names will change every day but if all you're doing is showing it to a user it matters less. If you're working on it using some object oriented modelling then you can't easily have an object with property names that relate to all available dates - it's so hard to work with data of this form, mapped to static property names that you wouldn't do it, you'd just leave the data in a datatable or similar and adjust your code logic to cope with varying column names

There are a few common ways to pivot data

```
SELECT *
FROM (select result, datetime from [lfplog].[dbo].[d_lfpLog]) a -- don't need a subquery if table only contains two columns
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR DateTime IN ([2021-04-01],[2021-04-02],[2021-04-03])
) x
```

You could also conditionally aggregate:

```
SELECT 
  Result ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN datetime = '2021-04-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2021-04-01",
  SUM(CASE WHEN datetime = '2021-04-02' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2021-04-02",
  SUM(CASE WHEN datetime = '2021-04-03' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "2021-04-03"
FROM [lfplog].[dbo].[d_lfpLog] 
group by result
```

You could even join the table to itself 3 times `on result = result and datetime = whatever`

All these methods require you to form the query yourself dynamically (in c#). You can't tell sqlserver "pivot this data" and expect it will find the columns itself - you have to be explicit about the column names. You either have to generate dates that you will put in (using string concat; it cannot be parameterized) programmatically it you'll have to run a query to discover what dates are in the table and concat them into the query text

By this I mean your code needs to be like:

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2021,4,1);
string cols = string.Join(',', Enumerable.Range(0,3).Select(x => d.AddDays(x).ToString("[yyyy-MM-dd]"));
string sql = $@"SELECT *
FROM (select result, datetime from [lfplog].[dbo].[d_lfpLog]) a
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR DateTime IN ({cols})
) x";
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I decided to loop query day by day and display it in front end

Answer (score 1):

you can use  sql pivot for this result you want

```
SELECT Result,   
'2021-04-01', ' 2021-04-02','2021-04-03'  
FROM  
(SELECT distinct DateTime , Result as total
  FROM [lfplog].[dbo].[d_lfpLog] group by datetime, result order by DateTime, result asc) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
count(*)  
FOR DateTime IN ('2021-04-01', ' 2021-04-02','2021-04-03' )  
) AS PivotTable;
```